# How can I access to the parent folder

Tags: document, folder

I don't find how to access the parent folder. How can I add a button or link to access it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ribbon --> List --> Navigate Up

See: [Using Ribbon in SharePoint 2013](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-access-the-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2013.html), you may also need to click the gear icon on top right and select "Show Ribbon".

[image]

Comment: Where did you find "Ribbon"?

Comment: Updated answer.